# Codeigniter MySQL incorrect datetime insertion

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

In codeigniter before database insertion, datetime is correct.

```
05-08-2019 17:30:00
```

But in database it's 
`05-08-2019 5:30:00`
I tried to add timestamp in config.php.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

But no change in this behavior.

Comment: can you show your `date_format()` code how you insert it in DB?

Comment: $data['cur_time']=date('y-m-d h:i:s'); $this->db->insert('tb_user', $data);

Comment: if you insert it from mysql `timestamp` auto update, then check your server timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$data['cur_time']=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//changes `H` & `Y`
$this->db->insert('tb_user', $data);
```

> `H` will give you Hour (00 to 23)
>   `h` will give you Hour (00 to 12)
>   `Y` Year as a numeric, 4-digit value
>   `y` Year as a numeric, 2-digit value

Comment: I think this will work. Will try by inserting new data this afternoon